# View BIM 360 & Fusion Models_Forge Tutorial

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk

I am following Node.js language for "View BIM 360 & Fusion Models" tutorial from

[https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels.)

I created a folder structure as per tutorial and my server also listening.

Now I want to overlay multiple models in a viewer, Example: Arch, structure & MEP ,
How to add code and where? please help
See below screen shot of my folder from Visual studio code[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [viewhubmodels](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels) sample uses selected versions from your objects tree to render a specific urn on Viewer, so you'll need to change this default logic.
To leverage this sample to achieve multimodel, please refer to [multi-model refresher](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher) blog post.

You can implement the addViewable function described by the blog post in your sample to aggregate models by clicking.

You can achieve it by changing [ForgeViewer.js](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/3legged/ui?id=forgeviewerjs). More precisely [Initializer](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/blob/nodejs/public/js/ForgeViewer.js#L30-L35).

The sample just assigns a new value to [viewer](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/blob/nodejs/public/js/ForgeViewer.js#L19) each time we click on an item version. We can change this behavior to aggregate new models on click instead of replacing them by changing the current [Initializer](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/blob/nodejs/public/js/ForgeViewer.js#L31-L34) by the code below:

```
if(!!viewer){
  addViewable(viewer, urn);
}
else{
  viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'), { extensions: ['Autodesk.DocumentBrowser'] });
  viewer.start();
  var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;
  
  Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
}
```

addViewable is defined by the blog post previously mentioned.

```
async function addViewable(viewer, urn, xform, offset) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
            const viewable = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
            const options = {
                preserveView: true,
                keepCurrentModels: true
            };
            if (xform) {
                options.placementTransform = xform;
            }
            if (offset) {
                options.globalOffset = offset;
            }
            viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable, options)
                .then(resolve)
                .catch(reject);
        }
        function onDocumentLoadFailure(code) {
            reject(`Could not load document (${code}).`);
        }
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load('urn:' + urn, onDocumentLoadSuccess,     onDocumentLoadFailure);
    });
}
```